# Downloading failed. cURL error 7: . Wordpress can't update anything

Tags: wordpress, curl, updates

Hi!

Please, help. I want to update WordPress(or plugins), but always the same error: 'Download failed: cURL error 7: .'

> OS: Linux Fedora 30. Server: nginx. DB: MySQL 8.0. PHP 7.3

I have installed all the needed `PHP` extensions. Curl is working - I tested to download google HTML using curl and `info.php` says thas cURL is enabled.

Why WordPress can't update anything?  Nginx error.log does not have mistakes. On another laptop (Windows 10) with the same development environment, everything works.

What information should I give you to solve this problem?

[error on the `WordPress` site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuzkp.png)

[cURL info (`info.php`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRU6I.png)

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: which url is wordpress trying to connect to? can you show us a sample url?

Comment: Hi! WordPress trying to download file from this url: https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/ru_RU/wordpress-5.2.3.zip